# Basic rofi usage to edit shell command

Tags: i3

I am getting started with rofi under i3, and it seems to do a great job as a command launcher.

One thing I miss from xmonad is the ability to launch a command with arguments.  For example, under xmonad, I could launch "emacs --debug-init" to launch emacs with the debug toggled on.

1. I was hoping that rofi had similar functionality, so that I could
   select a command, but then add options, flags, and arguments before
   it launched.  Is that possible?
2. In a similar vein, can I ask rofi to launch inside a terminal for
   commands that need that?

Comment: Have you tried hitting `Shift + Enter` or `Ctrl + Enter`? On my system `Ctrl + Enter` does the trick for commands with arguments.

Comment: @Antoine, thanks.  Yes, I did finally figure it out.  I must say the documentation is pretty obscure to me on this point.